# Why is my code not outputting (just) numbers?

Tags: c++, function, output

exercise prompt for code: Write a program that tells what coins to give for any amount of change from 1 cent to 99 cents. Use coin denominations of 25 cents (quarters), 10 cents (dimes), and 1 cent (pennies). Do not use nickel and half-dollar coins. Your program will use the following function (among others):
void compute_coins(int coin_value, int& num, int& amount_left);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void prompt(int *amount_left);
void remaining_change(int *amount_left, int coin_value);
void compute_coins(int coin_value, int *num, int *amount_left);
void output(string coin_name, int *num);



int main() {
    int change = 0, num = 0, amount_left = 0;
    const int quarter = 25, dime = 10, penny = 1;
    string q = "quarter(s)", d = "dime(s)", p = "penny(s)"; 

    prompt(&change);
    compute_coins(quarter, &num, &amount_left);
    remaining_change(&amount_left, quarter);
    output(q, &num);

    compute_coins(dime, &num, &amount_left);
    remaining_change(&amount_left, dime);
    output(d, &num);

    compute_coins(penny, &num, &amount_left);
    output(p, &num);

}

void prompt(int *change)
{
  cout << "How much change is there? ";
  cin >> *change;
  cout << "You entered " << change << endl;
  cout << "That is equal to: ";
}

void remaining_change(int *amount_left, int coin_value)
{
    *amount_left = (*amount_left % coin_value);
}
void compute_coins(int coin_value, int *num, int *amount_left)
{
   *num = *amount_left / coin_value; 
}

void output(string coin_name,int *num)
{
    cout << num << " " << coin_name << ", ";
}
```

Comment: also this is what it outputs:
How much change is there?  54
You entered 0x7fff6d1cbf08
That is equal to: 0x7fff6d1cbf04 quarter(s), 0x7fff6d1cbf04 dime(s), 0x7fff6d1cbf04 penny(s),

Comment: it is outputting memory address, you should output pointer data instead of its memory address.  cout<<*change;

Comment: i got the code to put out the data now but it just outputs 0's.

Comment: @Al13y then you need to look at your program logic, maybe run through a debugger. One issue is that `amount_left` will never be anything other than `0`.

Comment: yeah. i think i was originally gonna use change but wrote it all using amount_left. i fixed it. i am trying to optimize it by making the set of functions in main their own functions so main will only call one line for quarters, dimes and pennies but im just getting more and more errors so i think ill leave it for now.

Answer (score 1):

In `prompt()`, `change` is a pointer, so in order to output the value that `change` points to you would need to modify this line:

```
cout << "You entered " << change << endl;
```

to:

```
cout << "You entered " << *change << endl;
```

Better still, though, you could use a *reference* rather than a pointer:

```
void prompt(int &change)
{
    cout << "How much change is there? ";
    cin >> change;
    cout << "You entered " << change << endl;
    cout << "That is equal to: ";
}
```

and then you would just call this as:

```
prompt(change);
```

This is much more idiomatic C++ – the pointer method is more "old skool" C-style programming.

Ditto for the other places where you are printing the pointer itself, e.g. `num`.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting the value of the pointers, not the value of the object pointed to.

The simple fix is to dereference the pointers first:

```
cout << "You entered " << *change << endl;
//                        ^

cout << *num << " " << coin_name << ", ";
//      ^
```

However, I'd suggest not using pointers for things like this at all. For built-in types you should take a reference when you want to update the variable and a value otherwise.

Personally I wouldn't update those variables from inside the functions either, I'd carry out the necessary input or calculation and return a value to be assigned.